# Can I define a path to my 404 template?

Tags: templating, 404-page

Wanting to move static/single templates in to a directory `pages` and thus, the path to my 404 template is now `pages/404.html`. I don't necessarily need dynamic content [as asked here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/390/whats-the-best-way-to-set-up-a-content-manageable-404-page). Is there a config setting I can use to point the default 404 URI behavior to that template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use [errorTemplatePrefix](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#errorTemplatePrefix).

```
'errorTemplatePrefix' => "pages/",
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's more than you ever wanted to know on 404 and error templates in Craft CMS: [Handling Errors Gracefully in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/handling-errors-gracefully-in-craft-cms#handling-exceptions-on-the-frontend)